# Layout Jerking when RecyclerView inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Im creating RecyclerView and ListView inside ScrollView and im getting problems with the scroll.. The scroll is Jerking (unable to get smooth scroll), I know its the problem with the RecyclerView inside the ScrollView, because layout is scrolling without any problem when swiping until the ListView exists but once RecyclerView items enter the layout it starts to jerk( only scrolling with the finger, no proper scroll when finger is taken off). Here is the code in the xml

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lv_home_dropdown"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@color/colorWhite"
            android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/recycleView"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Making a ListView with height `wrap_content` is going to cause all kinds of issues. Take the ListView out of the ScrollView and your problems will go away.

Comment: @dharms: I need the data in the RecyclerView to be followed after the content in the ListView.. If i make the ListView to match_parent, that would be a problem!

Comment: You can add that view as a footer to the ListView.

Comment: What affect are you trying to obtain? There may be an easier way that does not involve nested scrolling views.

Comment: @cyroxis: I have 2 buttons(Horizontally) on the top, one i click the 1st button the listview will be populated with items and the recyclerview will go down along with the list height. Same thing happens for the 2nd button the same listview gets populated with different list items and the same recyclerview will go down !

Answer (score 2):

1. Nested views that scroll along the same axis have always been
   problematic on Android. Recently Google has added nested scrolling
   support. In order to have this on older platform levels, you should
   use the views in the support library like `NestedScrollView` and
   `RecyclerView`.
2. ListView does not work with `wrap_content` as its height. You can do
   this with `RecyclerView` if you have the latest version of the
   `RecyclerView` support library. Besides, you are already using `RecyclerView` in one place, you might as well use them exclusively.
3. ListView is not really meant to be a "drop down". Perhaps you should consider a `Spinner` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have it finally.!!
Just add the following line of code in you class where you are calling the RecyclerView

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)tmpView.findViewById(R.id.recycleView);
mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

It works for me!